# Anyone else knows what does this mean?

Tags: java

```
static final boolean $assertionsDisabled = !java/util/TaskQueue.desiredAssertionStatus();
```

which was seen in the source file `java.util.TaskQueue.java`

Comment: So what's the question? It's a boolean variable set to the inverted return value of the `desiredAssertionStatus()` method. Apprently, the `java/util/TaskQueue` part is no valid Java source code.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting [*6.2.1 Assertion Overhead*](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+performance+tuning/Chapter+6.+Exceptions+Assertions+Casts+and+Variables/6.2+Assertions/):

> It is useful to understand how the assertion mechanism works to see how assertion statements can affect performance. When the compiler finds an assertion in a class, it adds a generated static final field named `$assertionsDisabled` to the class. The field is left unassigned (this is legal bytecode). The assertion itself is compiled into a statement of the form:

```
if ($assertionsDisabled)
  if (!boolean_expression)
    throw new AssertionError(String_expression);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tomasz Nurkiewicz. Perfect answer (+1). But I believe that this is not what HeJian asked. I believe he just did not understand what does this line syntactically mean.

Answer (score 3):

Since java identifiers can contain Latin letters,  $, _ and digits starting from letter where $ and _ are kind of letters `$assertionsDisabled` is a valid java identifiers of type `boolean`.

`java/util/TaskQueue.desiredAssertionStatus()` does not seem like a valid expression. Probably it should look like `java.util.TaskQueue.desiredAssertionStatus()`. In this case it is invocation of static method `desiredAssertionStatus()` from class `TaskQueue`.

This method returns boolean result. The `!` reverses the result.

The only question is what is it really? Since the obvious syntax mistake appears here (`/` instead of `.`) I assume that this line is a result of decompilation of java code or "bad" coding attempt. Am I right?

I have just checked source code of `java.util.TaskQueue.java`. It does not contain such line. So, I am pretty sure now that you got it from de-compilation. Do you probably have IDE plug-in that decompiles all classes if their source code is not found?

Comment: @HeJian, connect JDK sources to your JDK. The JDK source is located under your JDK installation directory in file `src.zip`

Answer (score 1):

It is because this class has an assertion, then the compiler creates this variable for itself.