# Java assertions - $assertionsDisabled vs $assertionsEnabled

Tags: java, assert, decompiler

Assertions in java compile down to a private synthetic static boolean added to a test - the proposal is nicely documented here:

[JSR Assertion Proposal](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/asrt_prop.html)

In it, we create

final private static boolean **$assertionsEnabled** =
        ClassLoader.desiredAssertionStatus(className);

and then

```
assert(X)
```

becomes

```
if ($assertionsEnabled && !x) { throw }
```

Which makes perfect sense ;)

However, I've noticed that what I actually get is

```
public void test1(String s) {
    assert (!s.equals("Fred"));
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

becomes

```
static final /* synthetic */ boolean $assertionsDisabled;

public void test1(String s) {
    if ((!(AssertTest.$assertionsDisabled)) && (s.equals("Fred"))) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}

static {
    AssertTest.$assertionsDisabled = !(AssertTest.class.desiredAssertionStatus());
}
```

I can't find any documentation as to why they went with a NEGATIVE test, rather than a positive test - i.e. the original proposal captured assertionsENABLED, now we use assertionsDISABLED.

The only thing I can think of is that this would possibly (POSSIBLY!) generate better branch prediction, but that seems like a pretty lame guess to me - the Java philosophy is (almost) always to make the bytecode simple, and let the JIT sort out optimisations.

( note that this isn't a question about how assertions work - I know that! :) )

( As an aside, it's quite interesting to see that this leads to incorrect tutorials! 6.2.1 [of this tutorial](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+performance+tuning/Chapter+6.+Exceptions+Assertions+Casts+and+Variables/6.2+Assertions/), which someone quoted in response to [a previous SO question on assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716970/anyone-else-knows-what-does-this-mean) gets the sense of the test wrong! :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

This is actually done for a reason, not merely for something like a more compact bytecode or faster condition execution. If you look at the [Java Language Specification, §14.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10), you will see the following note:

> An assert statement that is executed before its class or interface has completed initialization is enabled.

There's also an example that contains an initialization loop:

```java
class Bar {
    static {
        Baz.testAsserts(); 
        // Will execute before Baz is initialized!
    }
}
class Baz extends Bar {
    static void testAsserts() {
        boolean enabled = false;
        assert  enabled = true;
        System.out.println("Asserts " + 
               (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
    }
}
```

As `Bar` is a superclass for `Baz`, it must be initialized before `Baz` initialization. However, its initializer executes an assertion statement in the context of `Baz` class that is not initialized yet, so there was no chance to set the `$assertionsDisabled` field. In this case, the field has its default value, and everything works according to the spec: assertion is executed. Had we have an `$assertionsEnabled` field, the assertions for an uninitialized class would not be executed, so it would violate the specification.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean is actually implemented with an integer.  There is a common believe that comparison with zero is quicker, but I don't see any reason to use disable instead of enabled.

IMHO, as false is the default for boolean, I try to chose a flag which has a default value of `false`  In this case `$assertionsEnabled` would make more sense.

Comment: Indeed.  Which makes using $assertionsDisabled all the more confusing a decision  ;)  Also (fairly obviously), this variable is constant folded out of existence in JITted code anyway.  (verified with -XX:+PrintAssembly)

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like there's redundant work being done when you look at the decompiled java source - *you can't rely on this* - you need to look at the *byte code level*.

Have a look at the bytecode both the eclipse compiler and oracle javac produce:

```
                    #0: getstatic Test.$assertionsDisabled
                    #3: ifne #23
                    (assertion code) #6: aload_1
                    (assertion code) #7: ldc "Fred"
                    (assertion code) #9: invokevirtual String.equals(Object)
                    (assertion code) #12: ifeq #23
                    (assertion code) #15: new AssertionError
                    (assertion code) #18: dup
                    (assertion code) #19: invokespecial AssertionError.<init>()
                    (assertion code) #22: athrow
                    #23: getstatic System.out (PrintStream)
                    #26: aload_1
                    #27: invokevirtual PrintStream.println(String)
                    #30: return
```

Please note **byte code #3** - it doesn't need to invert the `Test.$assertionsDisabled` value, it only needs to perform a single negative test (i.e. it doesn't make any difference if it's a negative test or a positive test at the byte code level)

In summary, it's being implemented efficiently and without any redundant work being performed.

Comment: This is not the reason. `ifeq` with `$assertionsEnabled` would work just as fine.